# Java regex split string by comma but ignore quotes and also parentheses

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm stuck with this regex.

So, I have input as:

- "Crane device, (physical object)"(X1,x2,x4), not "Seen by research nurse (finding)", EntirePatellaBodyStructure(X1,X8), "Besnoitia wallacei (organism)", "Catatropis (organism)"(X1,x2,x4), not IntracerebralRouteQualifierValue, "Diospyros virginiana (organism)"(X1,x2,x4), not SuturingOfHandProcedure(X1)

and in the end I would like to get is:

- "Crane device, (physical object)"(X1,x2,x4)
- not "Seen by research nurse (finding)"
- EntirePatellaBodyStructure(X1,X8)
- "Besnoitia wallacei (organism)"
- "Catatropis (organism)"(X1,x2,x4)
- not IntracerebralRouteQualifierValue
- "Diospyros virginiana (organism)"(X1,x2,x4)
- not SuturingOfHandProcedure(X1)

I've tried regex

```
(\'[^\']*\')|(\"[^\"]*\")|([^,]+)|\\s*,\\s*
```

It works if I don't have a comma inside parentheses.

Comment: anything special about `not` and `()`!

Comment: Looks like what you want here is a full fledged parser and not regexes.

Comment: this is actually prolog command, but in this case "not" doesn't effect. Also in parentheses is a variables, but it could be empty.

Comment: interesting query. I wonder what persimmons have to do with knees or hand sutures. :-)

Comment: @JasonS I wish it was duplicate. I've spent more than 2 hours trying to find solution here. And I've considered that question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**RegEx**

```
(\w+\s)?("[^"]+"|\w+)(\(\w\d(,\w\d)*\))?
```

**Java Code**

```
String input = ... ;
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
          "(\\w+\\s)?(\"[^\"]+\"|\\w+)(\\(\\w\\d(,\\w\\d)*\\))?").matcher(input);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
"Crane device, (physical object)"(X1,x2,x4)
not "Seen by research nurse (finding)"
EntirePatellaBodyStructure(X1,X8)
not "Besnoitia wallacei (organism)"(X1,x2,x4)
not "Catatropis (organism)"(X1,x2,x4)
not IntracerebralRouteQualifierValue
not "Diospyros virginiana (organism)"(X1,x2,x4)
not SuturingOfHandProcedure(X1)
```

Comment: with example that I've given in the beging your Regex works perfect. But, unfortunately, with updated example not, specifically, part without any quotes. But thank you anyway, I'll try to improve it.

Comment: Check update. Added regex as per your new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use regexes for this.  Write a simple parser that keeps track of the number of parentheses encountered, and whether or not you are inside quotes.  For more information, see:  [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Would this do what you need?

```
System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll(", not", "\nnot"));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that I gave bad example. Of course "not" is not obliged here.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now with your updated example, I'm sure one of the other guys solutions will work for you then.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is no possibility of nesting `()` within `()`, and no possibility of (say) `\"` within `""`, you can write something like:

```
private static final Pattern CUSTOM_SPLIT_PATTERN =
    Pattern.compile("\\s*((?:\"[^\"]*\"|[(][^)]*[)]|[^\"(]+)+)");
private static final String[] customSplit(final String input) {
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher m = CUSTOM_SPLIT_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while(m.find()) {
        ret.add(m.group(1));
    }
    return ret.toArray(new String[ret.size()]);
}
```

(disclaimer: not tested).